# Como repetir HTTP requests várias vezes e simultaneamnte, sem delay?

Tags: c#, http

Preciso de uma maneira de enviar *http request's* várias vezes, sem alteração de nenhuma requisição.

Atualmente eu tenho utilizado Charles Proxy - pego a request de um app do iphone e assim posso repetí-la em meu computador. Charles Proxy repete quantas vezes for necessário, porém com certo delay entre as requests. Observei que o servidor não aceita a mesma request se for mandada após 200ms. Por isso, necessitava de um programa ou outro meio que pudesse enviar 30 requests, por exemplo, todas ao mesmo tempo, sem delay. Há alguma maneira de se realizar isso?

Não tenho controle sobre o servidor, que não é meu. Apenas pego requests prontas do iphone e repito no windows.

Comment: Que tipo de requisição? REST, HTTP simples? Existem várias ferramentas em várias linguagens que permitem você fazer isso. Não precisaria criar um programa específico, basta configurar a ferramenta com a quantidade de threads, a quantidade de requisições por threads ou o tempo de duração do teste.

Comment: http/1.1 POST. estou com a request aberta agora mesmo aqui.

Comment: Veja por exemplo [este exemplo](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/load-testing.html) de como fazer teste de carga com a ferramenta SoapUI (que faz SOAP e RESP).

Comment: Outra ferramenta interessante para testes de carga é o [Proxy Sniffer](http://www.proxy-sniffer.com/). Com ele você pode gravar o teste e ele gera o código (em Java) para você adaptar da forma que quiser, além de ter um sistema para você faz a execução dos testes gravados de acordo com os parâmetros solicitados. Enfim, é isso que você procura?

Comment: vou utilizar o proxy sniffer. Mas queria um programa que simplesmente pudesse repetir POST https de um servidor ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 1):

O Apache [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) é capaz de realizar o teste de carga que você precisa. É free e open source.

Apenas lembre-se que enviar muitas requisições para um servidor pode derrubá-lo ou deixá-lo muito lento, podendo gerar algo que será considerado como um **Ataque de Negação de Serviço,** **Denial of Service** (DoS) em inglês. Isso é especialmente grave quando o servidor não é seu.